# Apache2 is not parsing PHP files

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, virtualhost, php5

i have a problem with my server (VPS with debian+apache2+php5).
I have two virtualhosts, one is linked to a ruby  webserver and has a PRoxyPass from port 80 to 8080 and the second one is a normal website. Before doing the proxypass thing everything was working fine with PHP but now when i try to load a page, it wont parse and the php file is being downloaded.
this is the virtualhost .conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost domain.com:80>
NameVirtualHost domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain
ServerName domain.com

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost server.domain.com:80>
ProxyPass / http://server.domain.com:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

I also tried to add into the httpd.conf the following:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .phtml
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php4
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php5
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
</IfModule>
```

I tried to remove and reinstall php5.
Any help is appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXED!
i removed PHP5 and phpmyadmin AND THEN purged php5-common , then reinstalled the php5 and phpmyadmin and now it works.
YAY!

Comment: can you accept your own answer so the question is marked as answered please?

Comment: I tried but i can do after 2 days, that's what the alert says